# SQL ISNULL but also need results if nothing exists

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a query to export orders from my database. So far I can get it to pull the records if either a field in the 'extrafields' is null or has content but I am unable to figure out how to also include if no data exists in the 'extrafields' database I'd be very grateful if anybody can offer any help, here's what I have so far.

```
    SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(e.content) THEN ol.code ELSE CONCAT(ol.code, ' ** ', e.content) END as `ItemNumber`,
CASE WHEN ISNULL(e.content) THEN ol.name ELSE CONCAT(ol.name, ' ** ', e.content) END as `ItemTitle`,
o.orderID AS orderId,
ol.productID AS orderItemId,
ol.qty AS Quantity,
ol.price + ol.taxamount AS CostPerUnit,  
'' AS ProductOption,
0 AS ItemTaxRate,
0 AS DiscountPercent,
ol.lineID
FROM
`jss_orders_headers` o,
`jss_orders_lines` ol

LEFT JOIN jss_orders_extrafields e ON e.lineID = ol.lineID
WHERE
e.content!=" " 
and ol.orderID = o.orderID 
AND e.extraFieldID NOT IN (130, 114, 113, 111, 84, 81)
and e.exValID > 0
```

Comment: Which dbms? (Not ANSI SQL...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you reference a left joined column (the columns from `jss_orders_extrafields` in your case) in the WHERE clause, you force the join to behave as if it were an INNER join. Instead, make those tests part of the join condition.

```
...
LEFT JOIN jss_orders_extrafields e 
    ON e.lineID = ol.lineID
        AND e.content != ' '
        AND e.extreaFieldID NOT IN (130, 114, 113, 111, 84, 81)
        AND e.exValID > 0
...
```

Also, be consistent in your join style and don't mix implicit and explicit joins.

```
...
FROM `jss_orders_headers` o
    INNER JOIN `jss_orders_lines` ol
        ON o.orderID = ol.orderID
...
```

And remove the `o.orderID = ol.orderID` test from the WHERE clause as well.

So, putting it all together:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(e.content) THEN ol.code ELSE CONCAT(ol.code, ' ** ', e.content) END as `ItemNumber`,
       CASE WHEN ISNULL(e.content) THEN ol.name ELSE CONCAT(ol.name, ' ** ', e.content) END as `ItemTitle`,
       o.orderID AS orderId,
       ol.productID AS orderItemId,
       ol.qty AS Quantity,
       ol.price + ol.taxamount AS CostPerUnit,  
       '' AS ProductOption,
       0 AS ItemTaxRate,
       0 AS DiscountPercent,
       ol.lineID
    FROM `jss_orders_headers` o
        INNER JOIN `jss_orders_lines` ol
            ON o.orderID = ol.orderID   
        LEFT JOIN jss_orders_extrafields e 
            ON e.lineID = ol.lineID
                AND e.content!=" " 
                AND e.extraFieldID NOT IN (130, 114, 113, 111, 84, 81)
                AND e.exValID > 0;
```